# Accessing the Facebook API on behalf of a user in the background

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm finding it hard to understand the Facebook API using the PHP SDK.
I want to allow a user to authenticate themselves once and then be able to connect to the API as them on an ongoing basis. For example check their notifications or post on their behalf. 
Do I need to store their token so the PHP script can access the API without them logged on? If so, which tokens do I store?
And how do I retrieve Facebook messages? I understand I need higher permissions for this?

I appreciate this might seem an overly simple question for some, but I am really struggling to understand from the documentation and all the tutorials I've seen assume a lot more knowledge than I currently have.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can extend user access tokens to be valid for up to two month. But your app should not post stuff in the name of the user, when the user is not active in your app – basically, every single post has to be actively triggered by the user. (And if the user is active in your app anyway, then you don’t need an extended token, but can use the short-lived one.) And reading a user’s messages is not possible any more at all.

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with an app posting in the name of the user. Plenty of apps already do this such as Hootsuite, Buffer etc. And I'm pretty sure the apps can access messages. I managed to get a script working that does just that. The big issue is that I don't know how to get the script running on a schedule and which tokens I would need to store.

Comment: There is no issue with apps posting in the name of the user in general – but the user has to actively trigger every post, and has to write it. You should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) before proceeding. And accessing a user’s messages or notifications is not possible any more, the corresponding permissions have been removed, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations